# Work carousel efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like an awful lot of code and I'm guessing can be condensed and made more efficient somehow. Can anyone suggest this to me at all?

```
// Add the active class to the first element
$('.indexWorkDetailsInner:first').addClass('active');

// Next Button Click
$('.indexWorkRight').click(function() {

    // Move all except the active element to the left
    $('.indexWorkDetailsInner').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) { }
            else {
                $(this).css({'left':'-450px'});
            }
    });

    // Animate the active element off the screen
    $('.indexWorkDetailsInner.active').stop().animate({'left' : '450px'}, 1000, function () {

        $(this).removeClass('active').css({'left':'-450px'}); // Remove the active class, and move element back to the left
        $(this).next('.indexWorkDetailsInner').animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the next element in to view
        $('.indexWorkDetailsInner:last').after($('.indexWorkDetailsInner:first')); // Move the last element to after the first                

    });

});

// Previous Button Click
$('.indexWorkLeft').click(function() {

    // Move all except the active element to the right
    $('.indexWorkDetailsInner').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) { }
            else {
                $(this).css({'left':'450px'});
            }
    });

    // Animate the active element off the screen
    $('.indexWorkDetailsInner.active').stop().animate({'left' : '-450px'}, 1000, function () {

    $(this).removeClass('active').css({'left':'450px'}); // Remove the active class, and move element back to the right
    $('.indexWorkDetailsInner:first').before($('.indexWorkDetailsInner:last')); // Move the first element before the last item
    $(this).prev('.indexWorkDetailsInner').animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the previous element in to view

    });

});

// Add the active class to the first element
$('.indexMonitorWork img:first').addClass('active');

// Next Button Click
$('.indexWorkRight').click(function() {

    // Move all except the active element to the left
    $('.indexMonitorWork img').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) { }
            else {
                $(this).css({'left':'-370px'});
            }
    });

    // Animate the active element off the screen
    $('.indexMonitorWork img.active').stop().animate({'left' : '370px'}, 1000, function () {

        $(this).removeClass('active').css({'left':'-370px'}); // Remove the active class, and move element back to the left
        $(this).next('.indexMonitorWork img').animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the next element in to view
        $('.indexMonitorWork img:last').after($('.indexMonitorWork img:first')); // Move the last element to after the first                

    });

});

// Previous Button Click
$('.indexWorkLeft').click(function() {

    // Move all except the active element to the right
    $('.indexMonitorWork img').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) { }
            else {
                $(this).css({'left':'370px'});
            }
    });

    // Animate the active element off the screen
    $('.indexMonitorWork img.active').stop().animate({'left' : '-370px'}, 1000, function () {

    $(this).removeClass('active').css({'left':'370px'}); // Remove the active class, and move element back to the right
    $('.indexMonitorWork img:first').before($('.indexMonitorWork img:last')); // Move the first element before the last item
    $(this).prev('.indexMonitorWork img').animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the previous element in to view

    });

});
```

It is code for a work carousel. The first two functions move the text left and right. The bottom function moves the image screenshot.

Comment: Instead of looping, you can just select on both classes at the same time: `$('.indexWorkDetailsInner.active')`. Also, avoid empty blocks (you can negate conditions, you know). Also, looks like you are duplicating the entire thing – do it once, but make it configurable.

Comment: It is duplicated because the top half moves the text, the bottom half moves the image. I know calling `$('.indexWorkDetailsInner')` all the time is not good and it should be a variable. If I do this, is there a way to then call `:first`, `:last` and also do the part `.active` with that variable?

For example:

`var innerWork = $('.indexWorkDetailsInner');`

Is there a way to then do something like `(innerWork)+('.active')` to be the same as `$('.indexWorkDetailsInner.active')` and again `(innerWork:first)` to be the same as `$('.indexWorkDetailsInner:first')`

Comment: [Yes](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Excellent. Got it working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

With help from @Ingo I got it down to the following, which I think is better.

```
var innerWork = $('div.indexWorkDetailsInner');
var innerImg = $('div.indexMonitorWork img');

// Add the active class to the first element
innerWork.first().addClass('active');
innerImg.first().addClass('active');

function workAnimate(direction){

    var signOne, signTwo;

    if(direction === "right" ) { signOne = '-'; signTwo = ''; }
    if(direction === "left" ) { signOne = ''; signTwo = '-'; }

    innerWork.not('.active').css({'left': signOne + '450px'}); // Move the not active text to the left
    innerImg.not('.active').css({'left': signOne + '370px'}); // Move the not active images to the left

    // Animate the active element off the screen
    innerWork.filter('.active').stop().animate({'left' : signTwo + '450px'}, 1000, function () {

        $(this).removeClass('active').css({'left': signOne + '450px'}); // Remove the active class, and move element back to the left
        if(direction === "right" ) {
            $(this).next(innerWork).animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the next element in to view
            innerWork.filter(':last').after(innerWork.filter(':first')); // Move the last element to after the first
        } else {
            innerWork.filter(':first').before(innerWork.filter(':last')); // Move the first element before the last item
            $(this).prev(innerWork).animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the next element in to view
        }
    });

    // Animate the active element off the screen
    innerImg.filter('.active').stop().animate({'left' : signTwo + '370px'}, 1000, function () {

        $(this).removeClass('active').css({'left': signOne + '370px'}); // Remove the active class, and move element back to the left
        if(direction === "right" ) {
            $(this).next(innerImg).animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the next element in to view
            innerImg.filter(':last').after(innerImg.filter(':first')); // Move the last element to after the first
        } else {
            innerImg.filter(':first').before(innerImg.filter(':last')); // Move the first element before the last item
            $(this).prev(innerImg).animate({'left' : '0px'}, 1000).addClass('active'); // Animate the previous element in to view
        }
    });
}

// Next Button Click
$('div#indexWorkRight').on('click', function() {
    workAnimate('right');
});

// Previous Button Click
$('div#indexWorkLeft').on('click', function() {
    workAnimate('left');
});
```